# Attempted to load interface "NotExistingInterface" from namespace

Tags: php, symfony

> Attempted to load interface "NotExistingInterface" from namespace "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Tests\Fixtures\Validation".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?    unable to understand this error
>
> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\
>   ClassNotFoundException
>   in \vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Tests/Fixtures/Validation/Article.php (line 5)

```
<?php
namespace Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Tests\Fixtures\Validation;

class Article implements NotExistingInterface
{    
   public $category;
}
```

I don't know the error. Please help.

Comment: Can you share what are you doing when symfony throws that error? May be share some code?

Comment: You are implementing `NotExistingInterface` interface and you have not imported using `use` statement.

Comment: It is good to use some IDE like PHPStorm. It would import what you need

Comment: The code you show is from a test inside the Symfony framework. It's not something I would expect your code to be using at all. What is causing that file to be run?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like:

```
<?php
namespace Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Tests\Fixtures\Validation;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Tests\Fixtures\Validation\NotExistingInterface;

class Article implements NotExistingInterface
{    
   public $category;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you have a class in your code called Article, and while using it in some code, forgot a use statement for it.

I ran into the same issue, which is why I'm here =).

It turned out that I hadn't put a use statement for my Article class in some other code, and when executing, it must have decided to use the Article class from the FrameworkBundle tests. Probably some autoloading/autowiring weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.

In a controller I needed my Article entity and the IDE suggested me to import the class and I clicked on the wrong one.

Check your imports (use)

You might have a...

```
use Symfony\FrameworkBundle\Tests\Fixtures\Validation\Article;
```

instead of a

```
use App\Entity\Article;
```